# Adding a task as child to a story by REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to add a Task as child to a story in PowerShell. But I keep getting invalid patch document.
Getting the two workitems work fine, but I cannot update the parent task.

```
$tfsToken = "MyPAT"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($tfsToken)"))

$defaultColletion = "DEFAULT_Collection"
$project = "MyProject"

$childID = "63573"
$parentID = "58342"


$childuri = ("http://tfs:8080/tfs/" + $defaultColletion + "/" + $project + "/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=" + $childID + "&expand=relations&api-version=5.0")
$parenturi = ("http://tfs:8080/tfs/" + $defaultColletion + "/" + $project + "/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=" + $parentID + "&expand=relations&api-version=5.0")

$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}

$childresult = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $childuri -Method Get -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json-patch+json"
$parentresult = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $parenturi -Method Get -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json-patch+json"

$childObj = $childresult.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$parentObj = $parentresult.Content | ConvertFrom-Json


$jsonArr = @()

$link = @{}
$link.Add("rel","System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward")
$link.Add("url",$childObj.value.url)

$atts = @{}
$atts.Add("isLocked",$false)
$atts.Add("name","Child")

$link.Add("attributes",$atts)

$relations = @{}
$relations.add("path","/relations/-")
$relations.Add("op","add")
$relations.Add("value",$link)
$jsonArr += $relations
$body = $jsonArr | ConvertTo-Json

$resultUpdate = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($parentObj.value.url + "?api-version=5.0") -Method Patch -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Body $body
```

Comment: Could you also post the error that Powershell is throwing, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write your body, you`ll find only one update statement:
[image]

However, the body should contain `[]`. So, the simple way just add brackets.

```
$body = "[$body]"
```

[image]

Or convert your body with:

```
$body = ConvertTo-Json @($jsonArr) -Depth 5
```